# Ensemble in R using SVM

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to classify some data using SVM in R.

The data set:

```
D1 | D2 | D3 | word1 | word2 |...
1  | 2  | 3  | 0     | 1     |
3  | 2  | 1  | 1     | 0     |
```

D1, D2, D3 take values from 0 to 9 and each word takes a 0/1 value.

First I want to build a classificator that predicts D1 based on word1, word2, etc. Then I want to build a classificator that predicts D2 based on what it predicted in D1 and the words.
D1, D2 and D3 used to be a single number of 3 digits and there is a relation between a digit and the prior one.

So far I have:

```
trainD1 <- train[,-1]
trainD1$D2 <- NULL
trainD1$D3 <- NULL

modelD1 <- svm( train$D1~., trainD1, type="C-classification")
```

But I'm completely lost, any help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Oh, you mean an ensemble? OK can you please provide reproducible data?

Comment: @Hack-R right an ensemble (I didn't knew the correct term, thanks), here is some data drive.google.com/open?id=0B7JXHHQ_-5IVZWdPS3ZCcGZ4Y0k

Comment: Thanks. So, just to make sure you know, you've got more explanatory variables than observations, which means too few degrees of freedom. I know that this is a subset of your total data, but for my answer I will have to limit the number of X variables.

Comment: @Hack-R thank you!, and yes, I'm aware the dataset should be way bigger to avoid this happening but it is the main problem with this data, the list of possible words is way too big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you already know this but I just want to make sure I cover my bases -- if D1 and D2 are predictive of D3 then it will always be better to use the actual values of D1 and D3 rather than predictions of them.

I will assume for the purposes of this question that D1 and D2 may not be present in your prediction data set, so that's why you have to predict them. It may still be more accurate to directly predict D3 from the "word" variables, but that's outside of the scope of this question.

```
train <- read.csv("trainingSmallExtra.csv")

require(e1071)
d1 <- svm(  x = train[,5:100], # arbitrary subset of words
            y = train$D1,
            gamma = 0.1)

d1.predict <- predict(d1)
train      <- cbind(d1.predict, train)
x_names    <- c("d1.predict", train[,6:101])

d2 <- svm(  x = x_names,  # d1 prediction + arbitrary subset of words
            y = train$D2,
            gamma = 0.1)

d2.predict <- predict(d2)
train      <- cbind(d2.predict, train)

x_names <- c("d1.predict", "d2.predict", colnames(train)[25:150]) 
  
final <- svm(  x = train[,x_names], 
               y = train$D3,
               gamma = 0.1)

summary(final)
```

> Call: svm.default(x = train[, x_names], y = train$D3, gamma = 0.1)
>
> Parameters:    SVM-Type:  eps-regression   SVM-Kernel:  radial
>
> ```
>    cost:  1 
>   gamma:  0.1 
> epsilon:  0.1
> ```
>
> Number of Support Vectors:  932

This is just to show you the process. In your code you will want to use more of the words and set whatever options you think are most appropriate.

I recommend using a holdout sample or cross-validation for benchmarking performance. Compare the ensemble model with a single model that tries to predict D3 directly from the words by examining their performance benchmarks.

Comment: I'm not sure of why you select `colnames(train)[25:150]` in the final part, shouldn't it be `[7:102]`? I think you are missing a `as.matrix` in the final part.

Comment: @daisymoon I selected the words to include arbitrarily because it's just an example (also I figured if I'm going to take a subset I should get some words that were *not* used to predict D1 and D2 so that it's closer to being orthogonal data).  It didn't seem to need the `as.matrix` in the last step; I was probably being overly cautious to use it earlier on. UPDATE: I just checked and indeed, you do not need `as.matrix` at all.

Comment: @daisymoon  Please feel free to upvote or mark it as the solution if this was helpful :)

Comment: oh right it makes sense. I just noted that when you calculate d2 you're not using the value d1.predict but for d3 you use both d1.predict and d2.predict, was it intentional?

Comment: @daisymoon You're right that was a mistake. I will fix it.

Comment: great, now at least I have an idea of how to make this work. Thank you!